# Zipping on the iPad: Is it worth it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, zip

I have several files out on a server which my user downloads into their application. Total the files are around 14.1 MB. If I compress the files it comes out to be around 13.2 MB.

Going through a few trial runs I've noticed that the ipad takes a very long time to unzip the files which leaves me wondering. 
Would using archives to download data to the ipad be a more logical approach? Would unzipping on the ipad2 be significantly faster? 
Unfortunately I don't have access to the server I am downloading from or an iPad2. So I have to make this judgement without significant amount of testing. Has anybody had any experience with zipping files on ios?

Comment: This question does not belong here.  Please read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  It is not a a specific programming problem or a software algorithm question or a question about software tools commonly used by programmers.

Comment: Is there any reason that you cannot bundle the files with your application? This way you avoid the zipping completely.

Comment: seems like a valid architectural question to me.

Comment: Yes, There around 300 separate packages that can be downloaded. The above file sizes are just a sample from one of them.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I'm sorry.  I'm kind-of new to this site, and I didn't think the question was about programming.  Again, my apologies.

Comment: @wizlog - no worries! I'm kind of new here myself, but I like how you've already gotten the hang of commenting (with @ symbols and everything).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann ([I](http://superuser.com/users/81403/wizlog) get tons of practice on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), and am just trying to expand my influence on the greater internet community)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save .9Mb it probably isn't worth it if it doesn't cause a performance issue, unless they need to download this amount of information many times.  Really, you'll need to test it out to know for sure for your particular case. Also, there should be a way to stream unzip the incoming document so it can be mostly unzipped before it finishes downloading.

Comment: Interesting concept, I've never heard of doing anything like that on ios. I'll have to do a bit of searching.

Comment: The zip format isn't really good to unzip on the fly as the "header" is placed last in the file. But because each file is compressed separately it's possible to get the files one by one. See Pinch-ObjC http://forrst.com/posts/Now_in_ObjC_Pinch_Retrieve_a_file_from_inside-I54